# Entire page as a dropzone for drag and drop

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

While writing web apps that took file input, I wanted to use drag 'n' drop, but I didn't want just a small dropzone on the page. I thought it would be more convenient if you could drop anywhere on the page. Luckily, the window.ondrop event fires anywhere on the page, but I wanted some fancy effect to show the user visually that drag/drop was possible.

To do that, all that was needed was detect when a file was *dragged into the window*, and when it was *dragged out*, to trigger an effect that showed the user that the app was drag-enabled. Turns out that drag events are not that convenient. I assumed that `window.ondragenter` would trigger only once, when the user entered the page. Then when you left the window, it'd trigger `window.ondragleave`. Wrong. It's constantly firing as the mouse moves over child elements in the page.

I looked at what properties were available in the event object, trying to find anything that could isolate what I needed, but nothing worked. The furtherest I got was being able to change the background color of `body`. And only if there was nothing else on the page.

Tons of file upload sites got it right. Imgur and WeTransfer for example. Their sites were all spahetti-coded and compressed to the point of unreadability, and I couldn't find anything on the subject by googling.

So how can this be done?

Comment: I know it's 6 years later, but it appears to now be possible to use Javascript to bind a handler to `drop` and `dragover` on the root HTML element of the page.  Is there any reason this is a bad idea?

Comment: Ah, another question exists for doing this much more simply using HTML5 and the root `html` element as the drop target.  Yes, this does work fine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144881/how-do-i-detect-a-html5-drag-event-entering-and-leaving-the-window-like-gmail-d

Comment: @pbarranis I don't get what you're asking. The question you linked is _exactly_ the same problem, just worded differently. He's talking about **inconsistent firing of `dragenter`/`dragleave`**. My answer addresses the root issue, whereas the alternative answer takes the `setTimeout` approach that Gmail and Imgur used around 2013. I specifically tried to find a better, more responsive solution than `setTimeout`. My solution _does_ use JavaScript to bind to drag events to the root element (`window`). It is not a bad idea, because I already do it.

Comment: Well to be fair, that question is specifically "how do I highlight a _small_ dropzone as soon as the user drags into the page". This one is "highlight the _entire page_ as a dropzone as soon as the user drags into the page". But the underlying mechanic is similar.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The trick is to use a dropzone covering the entire page, and caching the `target` of `window.ondragenter` to compare with the `target` of  `window.ondragleave`.

**First, the dropzone:**

```
<style>
div.dropzone
{
    /* positions to point 0,0 - required for z-index */
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; 
    /* above all elements, even if z-index is used elsewhere
       it can be lowered as needed, but this value surpasses
       all elements when used on YouTube for example. */
    z-index: 9999999999;               
    /* takes up 100% of page */
    width: 100%; height: 100%;         
    /* dim the page with 50% black background when visible */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    /* a nice fade effect, visibility toggles after 175ms, opacity will animate for 175ms. note display:none cannot be animated.  */
    transition: visibility 175ms, opacity 175ms;
}
</style>
<!-- both visibility:hidden and display:none can be used,
     but the former can be used in CSS animations -->
<div style="visibility:hidden; opacity:0" class="dropzone"></div>
```

Even though the dropzone will be covering the entire page, using `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` will hide it from view. I used `visibility:hidden` so that CSS animations can be used to animate the transition.

**Assigning the events**

```
<script>
/* lastTarget is set first on dragenter, then
   compared with during dragleave. */
var lastTarget = null;

window.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e)
{
    lastTarget = e.target; // cache the last target here
    // unhide our dropzone overlay
    document.querySelector(".dropzone").style.visibility = "";
    document.querySelector(".dropzone").style.opacity = 1;
});

window.addEventListener("dragleave", function(e)
{
    // this is the magic part. when leaving the window,
    // e.target happens to be exactly what we want: what we cached
    // at the start, the dropzone we dragged into.
    // so..if dragleave target matches our cache, we hide the dropzone.
    // `e.target === document` is a workaround for Firefox 57
    if(e.target === lastTarget || e.target === document)
    {
        document.querySelector(".dropzone").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector(".dropzone").style.opacity = 0;
    }
});
</script>
```

*So here's the process:* You drag a file over the window, and window.ondragenter immediately fires. The `target` is set to the root element, `<html>`. Then you immediately unhide your dropzone, which covers the entire page. `window.ondragenter` will fire again, this time the target being your dropzone. Each time the `dragenter` event fires, it will cache the target, because this will be the target that will match the last `window.ondragleave` event that fires when you drag out of the window.

Why does this work? I have no idea, but that is how to do it. This is pretty much the only working method that triggers when the user drags off the page.

I believe it works because once the dropzone is unhidden, it will **always** be the last target. It covers every pixel of the page, even the `<html>` tag. This method relies on dragleave firing when leaving the window. <s>Unfortunately there is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656164) that prevents it from working properly. Please vote for it so it'll get fixed sooner</s>. As of Firefox 57.0.2, dragleave appears to fire properly. However, a workaround is required, checking `document` instead of the cached element:

```
if(e.target === lastTarget || e.target === document)
```

[Here's a JSBin of it in action](https://output.jsbin.com/puvidamahi). Tested working in latest Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11.

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, as the event.target returned by dragleave is HTML document, which does not match the last cached element (most likely the .dropzone).

Comment: @DannyLin Unfortunately there is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656164) that prevents it from working properly. Please vote for it so it'll get fixed sooner.

Comment: Ah, so the bug appears to be fixed now? Firefox reliably returns `document` as `event.target` when leaving window. I included this workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the accepted answer a little because didn't want to hide Dropzone. So maybe this tiny modification be helpful for others:

1- Made a full width hidden wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="visibility:hidden; opacity:0" >DROP HERE</div>
```

2- Show it on [dragenter] event:

```
window.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e){ // drag start
    // unhide our green overlay
    showWrapper();
    lastTarget = e.target; // cache the last target here
});
```

3- if user drop the file, pass it to Dropzone:

```
window.addEventListener("drop", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    hideWrapper();

    // if drop, we pass object file to dropzone
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone");
    myDropzone.handleFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);

});
```

I made a live demo with more details on [codepen](https://codepen.io/kran-chi/pen/dyVvQpO).
Thank you

Comment: Your CodePen is perfect and your solution works GREAT! Thanks.