# Check when file is being dragged to website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to check when a file is being dragged on to my website using javascript. I have tried putting a "hitbox" div covering the whole site:

```
<div id="Drag-File-Hitbox" ondragover="BGDragFileOver()">
</div>
<style>
#Drag-File-Hitbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;

    z-index: 999999999;
}
</style>
```

Whenever I drag a file to my website it does what I want but I cant click stuff in the background such as my navigation bar. I have also tried putting the ondragover event on the body tag but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you mean that you want to be able to drop the file into anywhere on your page, check this question: [How do I detect a HTML5 drag event entering and leaving the window, like Gmail does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144881/how-do-i-detect-a-html5-drag-event-entering-and-leaving-the-window-like-gmail-d)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/html5-drop-event-doesnt-work-unless-dragover-is-handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using jQuery instead, here is the code below that worked for others who might stumbleupon the same issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('dragenter', function(){
      do stuff
   });
});
```